# What does it mean when a Clifford group preserves conjugation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, density-operator

I am currently reading about Clifford groups/[gates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_gates) and am having trouble understanding how a transformation can or cannot preserve conjugation. For example, Clifford transformations preserving conjugation for Pauli operators.

Answer (score 1):

There’s an incorrect statement somewhere.  The Clifford group maps Pauli matrices to Pauli matrices under conjugation.  Clifford does not “preserve conjugation”.  To be explicit, if $\gamma$ is in the Clifford group, then
$$
\gamma \sigma_k \gamma^{-1}
$$
is also a Pauli matrix (not necessarily the same).  The conjugation here refers to the sandwiching of an object between $\gamma$ and $\gamma^{-1}$

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!